# Не запускается Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Перестала запускаться VS.
При запуске некоторое время висит экран загрузки, а после появляется такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на "Отладка" видим следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал восстановление и переустановку — не помогает. Прекращению стабильной работы VS предшествовала моя работа с Git. Я откатил проект к предыдущему коммиту и синхронизировал его. Во время этого VS крашнулась и перестала запускаться.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте удалить кеш `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\`

Comment: @Ruslan_K, Не помогло. Теперь сменился код в отладке на [2096].

Comment: @maxwell Возможно вам было бы быстрей переустановить ОС, а затем студию накатить, как думаете?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Это очевидно вынужденная мера, которую оставлю на крайний случай. Пока хотелось бы разобраться в чем причина такого поведения VS.

Comment: @maxwell Советую также задать такой же вопрос на англ SO и/или другом сайте группы StackExchange (не знаю куда больше всего подходят такие вопросы), а здесь также указать ссылку на него.